# Property singular support of the convolution of distributions

Tags: functional-analysis, proof-verification, distribution-theory, regularity-theory-of-pdes

Let $u \in \mathcal{D}'(\Omega)$ and $U \subset \Omega$ open.
By definition we say that $u \in \mathcal{E}(U)$ if $\exists u(x) \in \mathcal{E}(U)$ such that 
\begin{align*}
\displaystyle \langle \varphi , u \rangle = \int_U u(x) \varphi(x) dx , \forall \varphi \in \mathcal{D}(U)
\end{align*}
and singular support of $u \in \mathcal{D}'(\Omega)$  is the set of all points $x \in \Omega$ such that not exists an open neighborhood $U\subset \Omega$ wich $u_{|U}$ is regular function, i.e.
\begin{align*}
\displaystyle \mathrm{singsupp}(u) = \lbrace x \in \Omega : \nexists U \subset \Omega : u_{|U} \in \mathcal{E}(U) \rbrace
\end{align*}
and then if $U_{max}$ is maximum open of $\Omega$ with the distribution $u \in \mathcal{E}(U_{\max})$ then
\begin{align*}
\displaystyle \mathrm{singsupp}(u) = \Omega \setminus U_{max}
\end{align*}
I'm trying to make a little better the proof that if $u$ or $v$ is a distrubution with compact support then

\begin{align*}
\mathrm{singsupp}(u \ast v) \subset \mathrm{singsupp}(u) + \mathrm{singsupp}(v)
\end{align*}

this proof it can be found in "Distribution Theory" by Duistermaat, page 130. It uses a regular version of the lemma Urysohn (Lemma 2.19 page 29), or as here [Proof of regular version of the Urysohn lemma](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1658925/proof-of-regular-version-of-the-urysohn-lemma)

As mentioned, I'm trying to better express this demonstration (and this proof is slightly different).

Proof.
We place $L=\mathrm{singsupp}(u)$ and $M=\mathrm{singsupp}(v)$. Consider  $\mathrm{Int}(L)\subset L$ and $\mathrm{Int}(M) \subset M$, by Urysohn lemma $\forall \delta > 0$ small
\begin{align*}
\displaystyle  \exists \psi \in \mathcal{D}(\mathbb{R}^n)  :  \mathrm{supp}(\psi) \subset L(\delta) \subset \mathrm{Int}(L)
\end{align*}
with $\psi(x)=1$ $\forall x \in L(\delta)$ and $0 \leq \psi(x) \leq 1$ $\forall x \in \mathrm{Int}(L)$, where $L(\delta)$ is a compact. Similary
\begin{align*}
\displaystyle  \exists \eta \in \mathcal{D}(\mathbb{R}^n)  :  \mathrm{supp}(\eta) \subset M(\delta) \subset \mathrm{Int}(M)
\end{align*}
with $\eta(x)=1$ $\forall x \in M(\delta)$ and $0 \leq \eta(x) \leq 1$  $\forall x \in \mathrm{Int}(M)$, where $M(\delta)$ is also a compact set. We define $u_1=\psi u$ and $u_2=(1-\psi)u$, and also $v_1=\eta v$ and $v_2=(1-\eta)v$, then $u=u_1+u_2$ and $v=v_1+v_2$, with $\mathrm{supp}(u_1) \subset \mathrm{supp}(\psi) \subset L(\delta)$, and $\mathrm{supp}(v_1) \subset \mathrm{supp}(\eta) \subset M(\delta)$, therefore $u_1, v_1 \in \mathcal{E}'(\mathbb{R}^n)$ are distribution with compact support.
Moreover $u_2 , v_2 \in \mathcal{E}(\mathbb{R}^n)$ (WHY?).
Consequently of the four terms in following convolution, only the last three are regular functions
\begin{align*}
\displaystyle u \ast v = u_1 \ast v_1 + u_1 \ast v_2 + u_2 \ast v_1 + u_2 \ast v_2
\end{align*}
this implies that
\begin{align*}
\displaystyle \mathrm{singsupp}(u \ast v) &= \mathrm{singsupp}(u_1 \ast v_1) \\
&\subset \mathrm{supp}(u_1 \ast v_1) \\
&\subset \mathrm{supp}(u_1) + \mathrm{supp}(v_1) \\
&\subset L(\delta)+M(\delta) \\
&\subset L+M
\end{align*}

Thanks in advance for any comments or corrections.

Comment: What happens if one of the distributions, e.g. $u$, has a non compact singular support. Why do you get $u_2\in\mathcal{E}$?

Comment: In addition: you don't need that both $u_2$ and $v_2$ are smooth since the convolution of a distribution with a smooth function is a smooth function.

Comment: Could you clarify what properties $L(\delta)$ has in addition to being compact?

Comment: I assume that $u$ or $v$ is a distribution with compact support just so because $u \ast v$ is well defined, otherwise the convolution of two distributions is not well defined. Instead you need to have $u_2$ and $v_2$ as regular function, otherwise I can not deduce that $u_1 \ast v_2$, $u_2 \ast v_1$, $u_2 \ast v_2$ are regular functions. See link of the proof of regular version of Urysohn lemma.

Comment: Of course, you are right that both $u_2$ and $v_2$ need to be smooth. But $u$ or $v$ might have noncompact singular support isn't it?

Comment: Yes, this does not matter, is not as to the supports (withat least one must be compact ) of the convolution of functions, to have $\mathrm{supp}(f \ast g) \subset \mathrm{supp}(f) + \mathrm{supp}(g)$.

Comment: I am worried because the cutoff functions have compact support so how can multiplying by $1-\psi$ "remove" the whole singular support.

Comment: It is the thing that I would understand. Perhaps by inclusions $\mathrm{singsupp}(u_2) \subset \mathrm{supp}(u_2) \subset \mathrm{supp}(1 -\psi)$, but $\mathrm{supp}(1 -\psi) \neq \emptyset$.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/42058/discussion-between-christian-and-john-martin).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not have the book of Duistermaat available at the moment, so I cannot compare your proof with the proof in the book. At the moment I see two problems with the proof:

1) Since you have $L(\delta)\subseteq L$ and not $L\subseteq L(\delta)$, I do not see why $(1-\psi)u$ should be a smooth function.

2) One of your distributions $u$ or $v$ might have non-compact singular support. Assume $u$ is the one where $\operatorname{sing supp} u$ is non-compact. Since $\operatorname{supp}\psi$ is compact there is no chance that $1-\psi$ can vanish on the whole singular support.

I think that these two problems are the reason why in the "standard proof" (e.g. given in the book of Hörmander) only the compactly supported distribution is split in a smooth and a singular part. In addition usually it is assumed that
$$
\psi(x)=1 \text{ for } x\in K \text{ and } \operatorname{supp}\psi\subset B(K,\delta)
$$
since then obviously $(1-\psi)u\in\mathcal{E}(\mathbb{R}^{n})$. On the other hand, in this case you have to show that also the convolution of the singular part with $v$ is smooth on a certain open set.

Comment: According to your last observation, we have that $(1-\psi)u \in \mathcal{E}(\mathbb{R}^n)$ since it vanishes inside the compact $K$ ? note that for me, $M(\delta)=M' + \overline{B}(0, \delta)$ where essentially $\psi(x)=1$ $\forall x \in M'$ and $M'$ is another compact, so I have applied the Urysohn lemma for $\Omega=Int(M)$. Perhaps I failed to specify this.

Comment: Yes, $(1-\psi)$ vanishes on $\operatorname{sing supp} u$ and hence $(1-\psi)u\in\mathcal{E}(\mathbb{R}^{n})$. In your argument $M(\delta)$ is a proper subset of $\operatorname{sing supp} u$, so there are points $x\in \operatorname{sing supp}u$ with $1-\psi(x)\neq 0$, so I don't see why $(1-\psi)u$ has to be smooth.

Comment: I can do this, if I take $\mathrm{singsupp}(u)$ compact, but how do I deduce the same thing for $(1-\eta) v$ with $v \in \mathcal{D}'(\Omega)$ with not compact support?

Comment: @JohnMartin: I think the above argument you need that $(1-\psi)$ is zero on the singular support of $u$ and $(1-\eta)$ is zero on the singular support of $v$. Could you add your argument for $(1-\psi)u\in\mathcal{E}(\mathbb{R}^{n})$ to your question since I still don't see it?